# Difference between Typeset Superscript vs. Unicode Symbol for Superscript

Tags: unicode, superscripts

For a Unicode font, is there any difference in height, placement, etc. between rendered text of `^{superscript}`, when compared to the Unicode character for `superscript` itself?
For instance: will the TeX output of `^2` be identical to `²` (\u00B2) in e.g. XeLaTeX -- or a WYSIWYG document, for that matter?

Comment: i'm pretty sure that it's not guaranteed that they be the same.

Comment: They use a different font; the `²` is taken from the standard font, `^{2}` is from the font at superscript size (for instance 7pt if the main font size is 10pt). It's better to make your intention clear and, in math, to use `^{2}`.

Comment: In text, it is generally recommended to use the specially designed super/sub-scripts if available and if possible. In (pdf)TeX, this depends on the font support files etc. as well as what the font provides. In Lua/XeTeX, there is http://ctan.org/pkg/realscripts.

Comment: Special case of [characters - Is there any reason to prefer a unicode symbol versus its LaTeX command counterpart? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618009/is-there-any-reason-to-prefer-a-unicode-symbol-versus-its-latex-command-counterp)

Answer (score 4):

You are talking about a math environment I guess (because you mention `$^$`).

I think the answer depends on the packages being loaded. In the example I think the package `unicode-math` actually makes `$²$` to expand to and `$^2$` (or something similar). Once this substitution is made the result (in math mode) is independent of the font selected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\usepackage{unicode-math} %try commenting this
\setmathfont{Cambria Math} %and this
\begin{document}
x² $x^2$ $x²$
\end{document}
```

[image: x2]

When you comment the marked lines you will see that then the result is not similar (in font *and* positioning).

[image: xx2]

So it isn't a categorical answer but it covers a common case.