# Is there any reason to prefer a unicode symbol versus its LaTeX command counterpart?

Tags: symbols, unicode, characters, chemistry

For example, consider the Swedish letter "Å" which is also the symbol for a unit of length in chemistry. When writing a document, there are three different ways to achieve this character:

1. `Å`
2. `\AA`
3. `\r{A}`

Given that there are three different ways placing the character `Å` into a document, is there any reason to prefer one over the other? Unicode is pretty ubiquitous nowadays, so is there any reason I wouldn't want to just place the symbol directly into the document?

Comment: They should all work in most contexts, but to typeset units, you might use a package like `siunitx`.

Comment: Can you remember how to insert the unicode character?  (Assuming you don't have a Swedish keyboard, of course.)  Does the insertion method even work in your environment?  Doesn't always in mine: after all, the point of LaTeX is that you can write in a simple text editor, which probably just understands ASCII.

Comment: Personally, I'm using Overleaf. On a mac, I can insert "Å" with `Option`+`Shift`+`A`

Comment: And people like me have keyboard with layer like this https://bepo.fr/wiki/Symboles_scientifiques.

Comment: For infrequent characters I prefer to use the [compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key). In many cases it is intuitive to use. On systems lacking this useful feature you can install additional software like [WinCompose](http://wincompose.info/) as an example. ------ @AmphotericLewisAcid I am wondering why your question in the title (why prefer Unicode) is negated compared to the question at the end of the body (why not to prefer Unicode)?

Comment: @pabouk: But you have the same problems (or at least I do) with compose keys as with unicode: unless you have memorize the key combinations for a few characters you use frequently, how do you go about looking up the characters you want?  While if you've used LaTeX for a while, you probably have a lookup table handy.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Do you use BibTeX to create a formatted bibliography? If so, let's assume the bibliography contains entries authored by persons with surnames `Åsgard` and `Æsgard`. You may be surprised to learn that BibTeX will sort these surnames alphabetically *after* `Z`, whereas BibTeX will sort `{\AA}sgard` and `{\AE}sgard` with the `A`s. If the publication is in English, your readers may get very confused if you spell the authors' surnames using `Å` and `Æ` and their publications don't show up under `A`. (For more information on the subject of using accented characters under BibTeX and the attendant sorting issues, please see the posting [How to write “ä” and other umlauts and accented letters in bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/5001))

Please note that the preceding paragraph applies to BibTeX — and to non-Unicode-aware versions of BibTeX in particular. (AFAICT, very very few BibTeX users employ `bibtexu`, which is said to be Unicode-aware.) If one uses `biblatex`+`biber` instead of BibTeX, the sorting issue can be adjusted on the fly to adhere to language-specific sorting standards. I.e., you can set suitable options to instruct `biber` to keep the entries authored by `Åsgard` and `Æsgard` with the `A`s or, alternatively, place them after the `Z`s.

Comment: Ah, that makes total sense! I figured there was something I wasn't considering, thanks!

Comment: I think this answer stands to be a bit misleading to many people, even though it's  correct. Many people use "use BibTeX" to mean "have a `.bib` file and do citations automatically", whether they are using `biblatex`  + `biber` or using e.g. `natbib` + `bibtex`. If you are using `biblatex` and `biber` there is no need to use `{\AA}sgard`. Furthermore, in the context of the rest of the document, there is also no need to use it anyway.

Comment: @Mico If you have a better option to not mislead people into believing that they have to not use Unicode if they do a bibliography, then please substitute my addition with it. Else, your current answer produces exactly that effect (hell, I do use `biblatex` and for some seconds started wondering whether I was doing wrong with my Unicode-only approach, until I read the comments —which a lot of people won’t do, whether they know biblatex or not).

Comment: @Mico Your edit is perfect, thanks!

Comment: @AlanMunn - I've added a second paragraph to the answer, to (hopefully) make clear that the first paragraph pertains to BibTeX (the program), not to bibliography creation in general.

Comment: On the other hand, a Swedish reader would be surprised to find Å and Ä along A instead of after Z.

Comment: @md2perpe - What's your point? Are you contradicting or otherwise calling into question the correctness of the statement "If the publication is in English, your readers may get very confused."? If so, on what basis?

Comment: @Mico. It was a response to that statement, but it was just a comment. If the paper is in English I think that it's best to sort Å and Ä as A. That will be least confusing to a majority of the readers. Only readers from the Nordic countries will be confused.

Comment: Ideally, the tools doing the sorting show know (or be capable of being told) how to sort the alphabet in use, regardless of how the characters in that alphabet are being represented. `\{AA}` and U+00C5 (Å), for example, should be treated identically. Whether Å precedes or follows Z is not something Unicode concerns itself with. (The order of the codepoints often aligns with, but should not specify, commonly used sort orderings.)

Comment: @chepner - I mention the programmable sorting capability in the second paragraph of my answer, as one of the features of biblatex/biber. BibTeX, which is far older than biber (to the tune of *decades older*) does not.

Answer (score 32):

Assuming you are using pdflatex (not a Unicode TeX such as Lualatex) then

- `Å` is defined by `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00C5}{\r A}` so it expands essentially to  to `\r{A}`
- `\AA` is defined by `\def \AA {\r A}` so it expands to the same thing as Å
- `\r{A}` is defined (in T1 encoding) by `\DeclareTextComposite{\r}{T1}{A}{197}` so it adds the character from slot 197 in the T1 encoding, which is Å

So to latex, all three are the same although it I wouldn't really describe using Å as "just place the symbol directly into the document"

Which is most convenient depends a lot on your keyboard, I can't easily type Å on this one for example.

Answer (score 16):

- Not every font includes the high Unicode glyphs, so putting one of them in a macro allows me to redefine it as necessary. You can still use the Unicode character in the macro definition.
- Sometimes it is more convenient to create a macro and write, say, `\undertie{}`, than to look up the Unicode point and enter it manually, or  to use a graphical character menu to select it.
- Some Unicode characters are not clearly rendered on the console (like combining characters), so those of us who write in an editor like Vim may prefer a macro whose meaning is obvious.

Comment: Agreed that is easier to input as a command. That is what I do as well. However, nothing stops the command definition to expand to a unicode character. For many writing systems as well as European scripts the shaping engine can also combine characters in a certain way.

Comment: Usually the keyboard mapping used in countries with non-English symbols includes these symbols so entering them is trivial.

Comment: @JackAidley Yes, I use US International  Alt Gr layout, so most characters like áéüñµç¡ are easy to type, but not the really high unicode values (music notes, prosody marks, emojis, etc.).

Answer (score 13):

PDFTeX, unlike XeTeX or LuaTeX, cannot understand combining characters such as U+030A.  So, Å in decomposed form would fail, and you would need to use Å (U+00C5).

This contradicts the Unicode standard, which says canonically-equivalent characters should have the same meaning, but the maintainers have said that it is a technical limitation of the 8-bit PDFTeX engine.

Not all hyphenation patterns understand combining characters in the newer engines, either.  I’ve had documents hyphenate between a base character and its accents.  This might have been fixed by now, at least to prevent a line break before a naked accent, but not all languages will hyphenate words with certain combining accents correctly.  In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, `\usepackage{inputnormalization}` will convert the text of the document into NFC form (that is, the precomposed standard form used on nearly all Web pages).

Answer (score 7):

- Using the unicode character will allow you to re-use the same portion of text outside of LaTeX directly. For example, you could email someone a paragraph directly from your tex file.
- Using the LaTeX command is often more intuitive, as you are simply writing the name of the character, rather than having to remember keyboard macros for unicode (unless you are using a keyboard mapping which includes these symbols).
- Whichever you decide to use, it is most important you remain consistent throughout your document.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to the other responses:

To generalize the ambit of the question, and for text mode only (math mode is a different realm), the answer is, "it depends", since which input method is the most suitable to use will vary with the circumstances, even within the same document.

With a few glyphs, combined with a keyboard, or keyboard overlay, or copy-paste source, or insertion mechanism, then "direct" input is one way:

[image: direct method]

Note that the unit symbol is a different glyph codepoint than the letter.

With a few glyphs, and without a keyboard or overlay etc, "indirect" input by specifying code points can be used:

[image: indirect method]

To save typing, commonly-used characters can be assigned to suitably named macros:

[image: named macros]

And to save continually swapping keyboards in multi-character, multi-script scenarios (assuming there are keyboards or overlays defined, or definable, to start with), or to save having to type many different codepoint digits, then a transliteration method could be suitable (for example, using expl3 find-replace commands behind the scenes):

[image: transliteration]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand\thdr{\rowcolor{blue!8}}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontface\fcunei{Noto Sans Cuneiform}[Scale=1.3]
\newfontface\fhiero{Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs}[Scale=1.5]
\newcommand\abos{\Large\phantom{(}}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareTextFontCommand\textcunei{\fcunei}
\DeclareTextFontCommand\texthiero{\fhiero}

\newcommand\ringa{Å}
\newcommand\alan{\textcunei{}}
\newcommand\seatedman{\texthiero{}}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand\doreplace[2]{
\tl_replace_all:Nnn  \l_mytemp_tl { #1 } { #2 } 

}

\tl_new:N \l_mytemp_tl 
\NewDocumentCommand { \tlcunei } { m } {%
\tl_set:Nn \l_mytemp_tl { #1 }
\doreplace{alan}{}
\doreplace{deity}{}
\doreplace{lady}{}
\tl_use:N \l_mytemp_tl
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \tlhiero } { m } {%
\tl_set:Nn \l_mytemp_tl { #1 }
\doreplace{RA}{xxx}
\doreplace{seatedman}{}
\doreplace{falcon}{}
\doreplace{ibex}{}
\doreplace{N5}{}
\doreplace{Z1}{}
\doreplace{C2}{}
\doreplace{r}{}
\doreplace{a}{}
\doreplace{xxx}{\RA}
\tl_use:N \l_mytemp_tl
}

\newcommand\RA{
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\tlhiero{r}\\\tlhiero{a}\\
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{c}
\tlhiero{N5}\\\tlhiero{Z1}\\
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{c}
\Large\tlhiero{C2}\\
\end{tabular} \\
\end{tabular}}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cl}
\thdr
Glyph & Method (``direct'')  \\
\hline
Å & U+212B ANGSTROM SIGN \abos\\
Å & U+00C5 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE \\
Å & A + ̊  U+030A COMBINING RING ABOVE \\
\fcunei  & U+12029 CUNEIFORM SIGN ALAN \\
\fhiero  & U+13000 EGYPTIAN HIEROGLYPH A001 : seated man \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{cl}
\thdr
Glyph & Method (``indirect'')  \\
\hline
\rowcolor{yellow!15}
^^^^212b, \Uchar"212B, \symbol{"212B} & 
\verb|^^^^212b, \Uchar"212B, \symbol{"212B}| \abos\\
\rowcolor{green!15}
^^^^00c5, \Uchar"00C5, \symbol{"00C5} & 
\verb|^^^^00c5, \Uchar"00C5, \symbol{"00C5}| \\
\rowcolor{yellow!15}
^^^^0041^^^^030a, \Uchar"0041\Uchar"030A, \symbol{"0041}\symbol{"030A} & 
\parbox{0.4\textwidth}{\ttfamily \textasciicircum\textasciicircum\textasciicircum\textasciicircum0041\textasciicircum\textasciicircum\textasciicircum\textasciicircum030a, \textbackslash Uchar"0041\textbackslash Uchar"030A, \textbackslash symbol\{"0041\}\textbackslash symbol\{"030A\}} \\
\rowcolor{green!15}
\fcunei ^^^^^^012029\Uchar"12029\symbol{"12029} & \verb|^^^^^^012029,\Uchar"12029,\symbol{"12029}| \\
\rowcolor{yellow!15}
\fhiero ^^^^^^013000\Uchar"13000\symbol{"13000} & \verb|^^^^^^013000,\Uchar"13000,\symbol{"13000}| \\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{cl}
\thdr
Glyph & Method (``named macros'')  \\
\hline
\ringa & 
\verb|\ringa| \abos\\
\alan & 
\verb|\alan| \\
\seatedman & 
\verb|\seatedman| \\
\hline
\end{tabular}





\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{cl}
\thdr
Glyph & Method (``transliteration'')  \\
\hline
\fcunei\tlcunei{alan deitylady} & 
\verb|\tlcunei{alan deitylady}| \abos\\
\fhiero\tlhiero{RA} & \verb|\tlhiero{RA}|\\
\fhiero\tlhiero{seatedman ibex falcon} & 
\verb|\tlhiero{seatedman ibex falcon}| \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your keyboard contains entry for these unicode symbols, it may be faster and easier to type them directly as unicode, or copy/paste instead of looking up the LaTeX command. It can also make the text easier to read and edit: `Jörg` instead of `J{\"o}rg`.